# Get pandas boxplot in one plot and matplotlib plot in another figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def csv_til_liste(filnavn):
    occuDF = pd.read_csv(filnavn)
    occuList=occuDF.values.tolist()
    return occuDF, occuList


occuDF, occuList = csv_til_liste("occupancy.csv")
plt.figure(1)
occuDF.boxplot(column = 'Temperature', by = 'Occupancy')
plt.suptitle('')

x=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y=(1,2,3,4,5)
plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

When I run the program, the two plots are plotted in one figure, but I want them in two separate figures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pandas.DataFrame.boxplot` takes an ax parameter, as written in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html#pandas-dataframe-boxplot).

So you can use:

```
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
occuDF.boxplot(column = 'Temperature', by = 'Occupancy', ax=ax1)
plt.suptitle('')

x=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y=(1,2,3,4,5)

fig2 = plt.figure(2)
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax2.plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```

Otherwise, you can plot in different subplots of the same figure by applying minimal changes.